# PDF convert utility taks a wide range of input

Tags: .net, pdf

I want to create PDF with word, excel, text, html input. It does not have to be a true .Net PDF library as long as it works with .NET code. Is there anything can handle that available?

Answer (score 0):

You could do that using [PDFCreator](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pdfcreator/files/PDFCreator/PDFCreator%201.2.0/PDFCreator-1_2_0_setup.exe/download) virtual printer...

Comment: PDFCreator works well for word, excel,ppt,txt files, but not htm lfile.

Answer (score 0):

Give the [Muhimbi PDF Converter Services](http://www.muhimbi.com/Products/PDF-Converter-Services/summary.aspx) a look. It installs in your environment as a scalable and robust Windows Service and has specifically been designed for use from server based applications such as ASP.NET.

It comes with a [friendly web services based interface](http://blog.muhimbi.com/2009/12/converting-office-files-to-pdf-format.html) that allows it to be used from most modern environments such as Java and .NET. It supports all common as well as some not so common file formats. [Watermarking](http://blog.muhimbi.com/2010/06/using-awesome-new-watermarking-features.html) and PDF Security is included as well. If you have SharePoint in your environment then a [SharePoint optimised version](http://www.muhimbi.com/Products/PDF-Converter-for-SharePoint/summary.aspx) is available as well.

Disclaimer, I have worked on this product so the usual disclaimers apply. Having said that, it works great.